# Obtaining transition density matrix

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I'm trying to assemble a transition density matrix on quantum computer using one-body excitation $\widehat{E}$ operator on 2 active spatial orbitals, i.e. on 4 spin-orbitals. The problem is, I need to rewrite all the four parts of $\widehat{E}$ only via expectation values

I have a one-body excitation operator defined as

$$
\begin{align}
\widehat{E}_{00} &= \widehat{a}_0^\dagger \widehat{a}_0 + \widehat{a}_2^\dagger \widehat{a}_2\\
\widehat{E}_{01} &= \widehat{a}_0^\dagger \widehat{a}_1 + \widehat{a}_2^\dagger \widehat{a}_3^\dagger\\
\widehat{E}_{10} &= \widehat{a}_1^\dagger \widehat{a}_0 + \widehat{a}_3^\dagger \widehat{a}_2\\
\widehat{E}_{11} &= \widehat{a}_1^\dagger \widehat{a}_1 + \widehat{a}_3^\dagger \widehat{a}_3
\end{align}
$$

and I need to evaluate a transition density matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle \psi_0|\widehat{E}_{00} |\psi_1 \rangle & \langle \psi_0|\widehat{E}_{01} |\psi_1 \rangle\\
\langle \psi_0|\widehat{E}_{10} |\psi_1 \rangle &  \langle \psi_0|\widehat{E}_{11} |\psi_1 \rangle
\end{bmatrix}
$$

without computing $\langle \psi_i|\widehat{E}_{ij} |\psi_j \rangle$ explicitly - as in real-world setting I have no statevectors.

For $\langle \psi_0|\widehat{E}_{00} |\psi_1 \rangle$ and $\langle \psi_0|\widehat{E}_{11} |\psi_1 \rangle$ I'm using the formula from (https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.1.033062)

$$\begin{align}
Re\left(\langle \psi_i | \widehat{U}^\dagger(\theta^*) \widehat{A} \widehat{U}(\theta^*)| \psi_j \rangle \right) &= \langle +^x_{ij} | \widehat{U}^\dagger(\theta^*) \widehat{A} \widehat{U}(\theta^*)| +^x_{ij} \rangle - \frac{1}{2} \langle \psi_i | \widehat{U}^\dagger(\theta^*) \widehat{A} \widehat{U}(\theta^*)| \psi_i \rangle - \frac{1}{2} \langle \psi_j | \widehat{U}^\dagger(\theta^*) \widehat{A} \widehat{U}(\theta^*)| \psi_j \rangle\\
|+^x_{ij}\rangle &= \frac{|\psi_i\rangle + | \psi_j \rangle}{\sqrt{2}},
\end{align}
$$
allowing me to evaluate expectation values on a quantum computer and obtaining the transition amplitude.

**But, while  the formula works for $\widehat{E}_{00}$, $\widehat{E}_{11}$, it doesn't work for $\widehat{E}_{01}$, $\widehat{E}_{10}$. Do you know what's wrong and how could I fix it?**

---

#### My guess

I'm suspecting, that the problem lies in the fact, that $\widehat{E}_{00}$ and $\widehat{E}_{11}$ are Hermitian, while $\widehat{E}_{01}$ and $\widehat{E}_{10}$ are not. So, is there any way around this?

---

#### My guess 2

Well, it seems, that the problematic part (at least from the "proof" what I've seen) is, that it works only with symmetric operators. But, according to the paper it shouldn't be the case.